# Installing PyArrow for the purpose of pandas-gbq

Tags: installation, google-bigquery, pycharm, pyarrow

I have tirelessly tried to get pandas-gbq to download via the pip installer (pip 20.3.3; python 3.9.1). Whenever I pip install pandas-gbq, it errors out when it attempts to import/install pyarrow.

I further tested this theory that it was having trouble with PyArrow by testing "pip install pyarrow" itself. This had the same error. I can post parts of the error if requested, but it's thousands of lines long and I can't even identify what the error is. I have 64 bit python, 64 bit pycharm, 64 bit machine etc etc.

Has anyone had trouble with this before. My solution was downloading Anaconda and I was able to conda install pyarrow, but I really don't understand what the problem with it all is. To further complicate the issue, I am able to leverage pandas-gbq by running my python project located in a venv created by PyCharm in cmd.exe, however I cannot run it in the PyCharm console.

When I have tried reconfiguring my python interpreter in PyCharm, it just says it cannot find the path to the project. Lotssss of confusion, would appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't think pyarrow works with python 3.9. See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html#python-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem myself,
what worked for me is reinstalling it with pip and restarting the Jupyter notebook

you might also try reinstalling it with conda

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
```

as per this answer below, for a similar question, which seems to cover the case

[Error importing pyarrow in jupyter notebook after pip installation of pyarrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216550/error-importing-pyarrow-in-jupyter-notebook-after-pip-installation-of-pyarrow)